# How do I programmatically prevent my google chrome extension from showing an icon beside the opnibox?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've developed a very simple extension and there's no reason for me to have an icon like this wasting prime real-estate:

[image: Example of context icon]

Is there any way through the manifest file or otherwise to prevent that context icon from appearing when my extension get's installed?

Comment: @chrisv Correct duplicate, but outdated answers. I'll fix that and close this.

Comment: @Xan Thanks for closing my question. I look forward to your updates to the answer since my manifest doesn't have a browser_action.

Comment: I closed it with a more recent question after all; but I _am_ going to update the old one. But log story short: "No, because Google thinks users are idiots".

Comment: Yeah, the answer was a bit old, but the comment below OP was Gold, @Xan ;)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, the answer would be no, especially when you are using `browser action`.

For `page action`, you could gray it out via [`pageAction.hide`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageAction#method-hide), however it's still visible.